# How to check a Script for Unity Inspector null parameters and incorrect values

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make my Unity game code as robust as possible, ideally I'd like to be able to throw an exception before boot of the game, e.g. at compile time, if a Unity Inspector parameter is missing or incorrect (e.g. null or out of range).

Currently I'm using a combination of `Attributes` and `UnityEngine.Assertions` on `Awake()` to check for null references or incorrect values; to throw an exception on boot of the game (rather than at an unexpected point during execution), e.g.:

```
public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    [Tooltip("Rigidbody of the Player.")]
    private Rigidbody playerRigidBody;

    [SerializeField]
    [Tooltip("Forward force of the Player.")]
    [Range(100f, 50000f)]
    private float forwardForce = 6000f;

    [SerializeField]
    [Tooltip("Sideways force of the Player.")]
    [Range(10f, 1000f)]
    private float sidewaysForce = 120f;

    private GameManager gameManager;

    void Awake()
    {
        // Cache essential references
        gameManager = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("GameManager").GetComponent<GameManager>();

        // Assert that all required references are present and correct
        UnityEngine.Assertions.Assert.IsNotNull(gameManager, "Member \"gameManager\" is required.");
        UnityEngine.Assertions.Assert.IsNotNull(playerRigidBody, "Member \"Rigidbody\" is required.");
        //UnityEngine.Assertions.Assert.IsTrue(ForwardForce > 100, "\"ForwardForce\" must be greater than 100");
        //UnityEngine.Assertions.Assert.IsTrue(SidewaysForce > 10, "\"SidewaysForce\" must be greater than 10");
    }

    ...
}
```

Is this best practice, or are there better methods for validating essential parameters before boot of the game?

Comment: Why do you need to do it compile time? You get a callback in the Editor called OnValidate() each time a variable is changed, its a good time to flag an error, rather than when you want to push the build out the door

Comment: I was thinking that compile time would be the earliest I could check for errors, but I wasn't aware of the [OnValidate()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnValidate.html) callback and it looks like it might be what I'm looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really on compile-time but if you want to do your checks everytime the Project is opened in Unity, code is recompiled or a new scene loaded you could use [`[InitializeOnLoad]`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/RunningEditorCodeOnLaunch.html) and  [`SceneManager.sceneLoaded`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager-sceneLoaded.html).

First have e.g. an interface like

```
public interface INullReferenceChecker
{
    void CheckReferences();
}
```

Then have a global editor script in e.g. `Assets/Editor/RunNullChecks.cs` (important is that is is placed in `Editor` so later stripped of)

```
[InitializeOnLoad]
public class RunNullChecks
{
    public static RunNullChecks
    {
        // first of all also add a callback so it gets re-run everytime you switch a scene

        // removing it first makes sure it is only added once
        EditorSceneManager.sceneOpened -= Run;
        EditorSceneManager.sceneOpened += Run;

        Run();
    }

    private static void Run(Scene scene, LoadSceneMode mode)
    {
        Run();
    }

    public static void Run()
    {
        // here it depends a bit on your needs
        // you either can check only stuff in the Scene like
        var nullCheckers = FindObjectsOfType<INullReferenceChecker>();
        // this gets only active and enabled components!
        // or you could include all prefabs, ScriptableObjects using
        //var nullCheckers = Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll<INullReferenceChecker>();

        // and then let them do whatever they implemented
        foreach(var tester in nullCheckers)
        {
            tester.CheckReferences();
        }
    }
}
```

Then you would have

```
public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour, INullReferenceChecker
{
    ...

    public override void CheckReferences()
    {
        UnityEngine.Assertions.Assert.IsNotNull(gameManager, "Member \"gameManager\" is required.");
        UnityEngine.Assertions.Assert.IsNotNull(playerRigidBody, "Member \"Rigidbody\" is required.");


        // you could also simply go for
        if(!gameManager) Debug.LogErrorFormat(this, "Member \"{0}\" is required.", nameof(gameManager));
        if(!playerRigidBody) Debug.LogErrorFormat(this, "Member \"{0}\" is required.", nameof(playerRigidBody));
    }
}
```

---

Another alternative might also be to use the [`[ExecuteInEditMode]`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ExecuteInEditMode.html) attribute.

This makes the

- `Awake` method be called everytime you open the project / load a scene / add a new component to the scene
- `Update` method be called everytime you change something in the scene

you might then however disable certain code blocks e.g. in `Update` checking for [`Application.IsPlaying`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application.IsPlaying.html) and/or [`Application.isEditor`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-isEditor.html).

Comment: Thanks for the information. The fact that this script can be removed when the game goes to production is very appealing!

P.s. I've updated my question to be more clear (that it doesn't necessarily have to be at compile time, but ideally before boot of the game, rather than at an unexpected point during execution).

Comment: This works for the Unity Editor only ofcourse ... it doesn't throw the errors for a build if that's what you are after I guess you have to stick to checking them in Awake